# Prevent server beeing flooded with requests

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress, spam

I'm hosting a Wordpress-blog on an Apache server (shared hosting).
For some reasons I've been receiving like 100 requests per second to xmlrpc.php for a few days.

The access.log looks like this:

```
...
188.138.33.149 - - [16/Oct/2013:17:46:03 +0200] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 403 212 "-" "GoogleBot/1.0"
188.138.33.149 - - [16/Oct/2013:17:46:03 +0200] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 403 212 "-" "GoogleBot/1.0"
188.138.33.149 - - [16/Oct/2013:17:46:03 +0200] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 403 212 "-""
...
```

In the .htaccess I applied the following rule:

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Is there a better way to prevent the spam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If most of your spam connections are comming from a small number of IP's you may block only those IP's from your .htaccess as described in [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

Answer (score 0):

Had this happen recently and it was killing the server and we're now using [**fail2ban**](http://www.fail2ban.org) to mitigate the issue.

Added this config to **jail.local**:

```
[apache-xmlrpc]

enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = xmlrpc
logpath = /var/log/apache2/*access.log
maxretry = 30
findtime = 300
bantime = -1
```

And create the filter in **filter.d/apache-xmlrpc.conf**:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST) .*xmlrpc.php
ignoreregex =
```

In my case the attacks weren't always coming from googlebot so made the regex a bit more broad but for my purposes there's hardly any good reason for any IP to be hitting xmlrpc 30+ times in 5 minutes.