# 100% CPU usage on my CentOS VPS

Tags: centos, fastcgi, cpu-usage, php-cgi

I have a 512 MB VPS and hosting 2 WordPress websites on this CentOS server. I have installed apache + mysql + PHP + fast cgi on this server. Everything was working great from last 6 months. I have 500 users per day on both websites combined. So no huge load.

But from last night (it's been 12 hours) I have 100% CPU usage and high memory usage. The websites as well as server is not accessible. I tried to reboot server thought it could just be some error but nothing worked.

It's the output of top, but I could not understand what is the problem and how could I fix it. Seems like there are tons of php-cgi & httpd processed.

```
top - 09:11:43 up 2 min,  1 user,  load average: 26.91, 10.07, 3.67
Tasks: 137 total,  28 running, 109 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 36.4%us, 57.5%sy,  0.0%ni,  4.1%id,  1.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.6%st
Mem:    511036k total,   505416k used,     5620k free,     3280k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    12240k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                  
  804 root      20   0 36160  540    4 S 11.7  0.1   0:03.69 rsyslogd                                                                                 
 1548 robert   20   0 51656  25m  812 R  5.8  5.1   0:00.76 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1549 robert   20   0 50412  23m  528 R  5.8  4.8   0:00.70 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1552 robert   20   0 50704  24m  764 R  5.8  4.9   0:00.64 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1568 robert   20   0 44940  18m  760 R  5.8  3.7   0:00.42 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1573 robert   20   0 38680  12m  792 R  5.8  2.6   0:00.32 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1584 robert   20   0 31964 6300  704 R  5.8  1.2   0:00.19 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1553 robert   20   0 49544  23m 1184 R  4.4  4.7   0:00.61 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1554 robert   20   0 49544  23m  972 R  4.4  4.7   0:00.60 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1557 robert   20   0 46288  19m  816 R  4.4  4.0   0:00.57 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1558 robert   20   0 46288  19m  836 R  4.4  4.0   0:00.52 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1563 robert   20   0 45452  19m 1104 R  4.4  3.9   0:00.49 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1564 robert   20   0 45452  19m 1136 R  4.4  3.9   0:00.46 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1565 robert   20   0 44948  18m  764 R  4.4  3.7   0:00.43 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1569 robert   20   0 35492 9872  768 R  4.4  1.9   0:00.39 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1572 robert   20   0 38680  12m  816 R  4.4  2.6   0:00.34 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1574 robert   20   0 38376  12m  784 R  4.4  2.5   0:00.30 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1576 robert   20   0 38388  12m  800 R  4.4  2.5   0:00.26 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1583 robert   20   0 32736 7688 1332 R  4.4  1.5   0:00.20 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1585 robert   20   0 31312 5832 1032 R  4.4  1.1   0:00.17 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1586 robert   20   0 31312 5856 1012 R  4.4  1.1   0:00.14 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1589 robert   20   0 30008 5320 1728 R  4.4  1.0   0:00.12 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1593 robert   20   0 30012 5208 1620 R  4.4  1.0   0:00.07 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1594 robert   20   0 30016 5156 1616 R  4.4  1.0   0:00.07 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1595 robert   20   0 30008 5320 1728 D  4.4  1.0   0:00.07 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1597 robert   20   0 12072  464  276 R  4.4  0.1   0:00.03 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1579 robert   20   0 32736 7844 1444 R  2.9  1.5   0:00.24 php-cgi                                                                                  
   28 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  1.5  0.0   0:02.65 kswapd0                                                                                  
  991 mysql     20   0  139m  14m  692 S  1.5  2.8   0:04.41 mysqld                                                                                   
 1186 robert   20   0 35172 6184  984 R  1.5  1.2   0:00.07 httpd                                                                                    
 1546 robert   20   0 53412  28m 1632 S  1.5  5.6   0:00.75 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1596 robert   20   0  2696  476  228 R  1.5  0.1   0:00.01 top                                                                                      
    1 root      20   0  2900  200    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.77 init                                                                                     
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                 
    3 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                              
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0                                                                              
    5 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                              
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.13 watchdog/0                                                                               
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.33 events/0                                                                                 
    8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cgroup                                                                                   
    9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper                                                                                  
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                    
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 async/mgr                                                                                
   12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 pm                                                                                       
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sync_supers                                                                              
   14 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bdi-default                                                                              
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd/0                                                                            
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 R  0.0  0.0   0:03.46 kblockd/0                                                                                
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpid                                                                                   
   18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpi_notify                                                                             
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpi_hotplug                                                                            
   20 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/0                                                                                    
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_aux                                                                                  
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksuspend_usbd                                                                            
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd                                                                                    
   24 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kseriod                                                                                  
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md/0                                                                                     
   26 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md_misc/0                                                                                
   27 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                                                               
   29 root      25   5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd                                                                                     
   30 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/0                                                                                    
   31 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto/0                                                                                 
   36 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld/0                                                                               
   38 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused                                                                                
   39 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 usbhid_resumer                                                                           
  189 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0                                                                                
  190 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_1                                                                                
  208 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 virtio-blk                                                                               
  263 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 jbd2/vda-8                                                                               
  264 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ext4-dio-unwrit                                                                          
  333 root      16  -4  2512  400    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.15 udevd                                                                                    
  361 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 virtio-net                                                                               
  364 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vballoon                                                                                 
  543 root      18  -2  2508  396    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd                                                                                    
  546 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kstriped                                                                                 
  600 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kauditd                                                                                  
  816 root      20   0  2020   88    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 acpid                                                                                    
  833 root      20   0  8940  512    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                     
  868 root      20   0  3044  184    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mysqld_safe                                                                              
  992 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 flush-253:0                                                                              
 1084 root      20   0 12960  636    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 master                                                                                   
 1091 postfix   20   0 13036  620    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 pickup                                                                                   
 1092 postfix   20   0 13108  672    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 qmgr                                                                                     
 1094 root      20   0 34900 5036   88 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.52 httpd                                                                                    
 1097 robert   20   0 20568 2320    4 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 httpd                                                                                    
 1103 root      20   0  3956  560    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 crond                                                                                    
 1106 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.05 httpd                                                                                    
 1107 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.02 httpd                                                                                    
 1119 postfix   20   0 14204  848    4 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 smtpd                                                                                    
 1134 postfix   20   0 13180  656    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 cleanup                                                                                  
 1138 root      20   0  2008   60    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                 
 1140 root      20   0  2008   56    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                 
 1142 root      20   0  2008   60    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                 
 1144 root      20   0  2008   64    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                 
 1146 root      20   0  2008   64    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                 
 1148 root      20   0  2008   64    4 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty                                                                                 
 1150 postfix   20   0 13232  680    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.04 smtp                                                                                     
 1151 postfix   20   0 13232  672    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 smtp                                                                                     
 1159 root      20   0 11884  740    8 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 sshd                                                                                     
 1160 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.09 httpd                                                                                    
 1164 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.03 httpd                                                                                    
 1165 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.03 httpd                                                                                    
 1172 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.05 httpd                                                                                    
 1174 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.07 httpd                                                                                    
 1175 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.07 httpd                                                                                    
 1184 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.04 httpd                                                                                    
 1185 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.09 httpd                                                                                    
 1187 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.05 httpd                                                                                    
 1188 robert   20   0 35600 5412   16 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.10 httpd                                                                                    
 1189 robert   20   0 35172 5264   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.03 httpd                                                                                    
 1190 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.02 httpd                                                                                    
 1191 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.11 httpd                                                                                    
 1196 robert   20   0 11884  748    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                     
 1201 robert   20   0  8220  448    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sftp-server                                                                              
 1208 robert   20   0 35172 5268   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.12 httpd                                                                                    
 1214 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.04 httpd                                                                                    
 1220 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.02 httpd                                                                                    
 1221 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.04 httpd                                                                                    
 1222 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.05 httpd                                                                                    
 1223 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.02 httpd                                                                                    
 1229 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.07 httpd                                                                                    
 1238 root      20   0 11884  736    8 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 sshd                                                                                     
 1260 robert   20   0 12020  752    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.59 sshd                                                                                     
 1265 robert   20   0  3180  308    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.14 bash                                                                                     
 1266 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.07 httpd                                                                                    
 1286 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.10 httpd                                                                                    
 1287 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.02 httpd                                                                                    
 1294 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.01 httpd                                                                                    
 1295 robert   20   0 35172 5224   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.06 httpd                                                                                    
 1296 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.02 httpd                                                                                    
 1332 robert   20   0 35172 5216   16 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.09 httpd                                                                                    
 1509 root      20   0  4324  668    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 crond                                                                                    
 1510 root      20   0  4324  668    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 crond                                                                                    
 1512 robert   20   0  6572  380    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 wget                                                                                     
 1513 robert   20   0  6572  376    4 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 wget                                                                                     
 1545 robert   20   0 53412  28m 1636 S  0.0  5.6   0:00.76 php-cgi                                                                                  
 1547 robert   20   0 53412  28m 1632 S  0.0  5.6   0:00.74 php-cgi
```

Can you guys look at it. Thanks

EDIT:

I have ton of these entries in `access_logs`

```
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:18 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:18 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:19 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:19 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:20 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:20 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:21 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:21 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:21 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:22 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:22 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:23 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:23 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:24 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:24 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:24 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:25 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:25 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:26 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:26 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:26 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:27 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:27 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:28 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:28 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:29 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:29 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:29 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:30 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:30 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
104.245.97.218 - - [14/Apr/2015:07:54:31 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 370 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

Comment: What do your weblogs say?  What is constantly being run here?

Comment: weblogs? do you mean website access logs for both websites?

Comment: Access logs for the server(s) that are producing all that CGI activity.

Comment: I don't know where are those? What is the location of those logs? I have edited question and posted something in my domain `access_logs`.

Comment: Consider switching to Nginx and lowering your PHP-FPM worker count. And possibly upgrade to at least 1024MB of RAM.

Comment: @AndréDaniel howz that going to solve the problem? As MadHatter pointed out, it's kind of ddos attack.

Comment: @Roberthue Nginx is less resource-hungry and your server is completely overloaded because of the number of FPM workers currently active. Even in case of a DDoS attack, you should try to keep the server at a reasonable load.

Comment: This is a DDoS attack from a computer at 104.245.97.218 that's attempting to knock your site offline. Whoever's conducting the DDoS attack is attacking many other sites as well; you're not alone. One of my sites was knocked offline for about 40 minutes on April 13 and about half an hour on April 14 by this same attack, which has been mitigated by blocking access to xmlrpc.php as described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're getting hit by [a pretty standard brute-force password guessing attack against Wordpress](https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/07/new-brute-force-attacks-exploiting-xmlrpc-in-wordpress.html).  As the linked article says,

> There are many ways to block brute force attacks. If you have a
>   dedicated server, you can install OSSEC (open source) on it and let it
>   automatically block the IP addresses that miss too many
>   passwords[...]
>
> There are obviously a number of application level tools (i.e.,
>   plugins) many will recommend within the WordPress ecosystem to help
>   with Brute Force attacks. Here is the thing, none of the ones we tried
>   will protect you from the XMLRPC calls, including our own plugin. It’s
>   likely why we’re seeing the shift in attack methods. Blocking at the
>   edge is going to be your preferred method until that gets fixed.

So it looks like a responsive ip-specific blocking tool like `fail2ban` is likely to be the way to go, here.  Failing that, [this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/546465/prevent-server-beeing-flooded-with-requests) suggests reconfiguring apache to refuse access to that script, which at least returns a 403 Forbidden instead of executing the script - that is much cheaper, computationally, than running it for each request, and would decrease the sever load.

**Edit**: congratulations on having `fail2ban` installed. Sadly, it's not magic pixie dust that automagically blocks all badness, it's a highly-configurable framework for responding to certain classes of entries in logfiles with ip-specific bans via `iptables`.  You will have to configure an appropriate jail before it can help you.

If that doesn't sound fun, you could ban this specific IP and see if it helps, with

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -s 104.245.97.218 -j REJECT
```

(assuming your server is on port 80).

Comment: I already have `Fail2Ban` installed.

Comment: blocking access to `/xmlrpc.php` will not help because I also noticed same attacks on other pages too like `/wp-login.php` and `/about` etc.

Comment: Yes, server is on port 80 but there are many different IPs. Is this random attack or targeted. I mean if someone is targeting specifically.

Comment: I can't tell you what the motive of your attacker(s) is, but there's pretty strong evidence that a lot of WP admins see this stuff.

Comment: If there are lots of sites are getting hammered then attacker is not targeting specifically my website. But still I need to find a solution to this issue. :(

Comment: Yes, and the solution's outlined above.  Go, find a logfile indicative of the bruteforcing, configure a jail, and let fail2ban get on with it.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking access to the xmlrpc.php will lower the cpu usage.  I've experienced this same attack, and although the attacker(s) were hitting other pages, blocking their access to xmlrpc.php made the site usable again.

if you are running apache, you can place the following in your .htaccess for WordPress:

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

If you do it this way, you can always allow access from known good IP addrs for blogging purposes, but I am assuming your intent is to get the site back up first.